# Is there a simple way to use 2 different classes, in other classes methods

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an Inventory system with its methods such as taking item from inventory and adding item to inventory. it usually deals with FoodItem type objects.
I have another class Sandwich type, and I want the inventory system to work pretty much in the same way it does with FoodItem type but with the Sandwich Type.

I started learning C# 2 months ago so I'm probably doing a lot of things wrong here.
I Dont hope to find a solution in this forum, but maybe someone could point me exactly at my misunderstanding with OOP and class inheritance and perhaps a specific guide that could help me better understand.

```
public class Inventory
{
    public List<FoodItem> container = new List<FoodItem>();
    public int inventorySlots = 1;

    public Inventory() { }

    public Inventory(int Slots)
    {
        inventorySlots = Slots;
    }

    public bool TryAddItemToInventory(FoodItem item)
    {
        if(container.Count < inventorySlots)
        {
            container.Add(item);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Inventory is full");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public FoodItem RemoveItemFromInventory()
    {
        if(!IsInventoryEmpty())
        {
            FoodItem item = container[0];
            container.RemoveAt(0);
            return item;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Inventory is empty: No item to take");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public bool IsInventoryEmpty()
    {
        return (container.Count == 0);
    }

    public bool IsInventoryFull()
    {
        return (container.Count < inventorySlots);
    }
}

public class FoodItem
{
    public string name;
    public  Sprite displayUI;
    public ItemType type;
    public float rating = 1;
    public StationResourceOutputPairs[] stationResourceOutputPairs;
    public float workAmount = 0;
    public float workRequired = 1000;
    public bool isSandwichBaseLayer;

    public FoodItem(ItemObject sourceObjectData)
    {
        name = sourceObjectData.name;
        displayUI = sourceObjectData.displayUI;
        type = sourceObjectData.type;
        stationResourceOutputPairs = sourceObjectData.stationResourceOutputPairs;
        isSandwichBaseLayer = sourceObjectData.isSandwichBaseLayer;
    }

    public void WorkOnItem(float amount)
    {
        if (!HasEnoughWork())
        {
            workAmount += amount;
        }
    }

    public bool HasEnoughWork()
    {
        return (workAmount >= workRequired);
    }

    public ItemObject GetResourceFromStation(WorkStations station)
    {
        foreach (StationResourceOutputPairs pair in stationResourceOutputPairs)
        {
            if (pair.station == station)
            {
                return pair.output;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

sandwich class is incomplete currently but this example holds the sorta class i would like to use

```
public class Sandwich 
{
    public float rating = 0;
    public List<string> listOfIngredients = new List<string>();

    public Sandwich()
    {

    }
}
```

I want to be able to store Sandwich type items in the same inventory class. and as far as the inventory class goes, treat them with the same methods.

Comment: `isSandwichBaseLayer` seems like a code smell. Also, the logic for `IsInventoryFull` seems backwards; it returns `true` when the count is less than the inventorySlots.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I would say to create an interface having the minimum requirements both FoodItem and SandwichItem have to have in order to be stored in the Inventory, let's say IFoodItem.

```
public interface IFoodItem {
 //any property or method FoodItem and SandwichItem share
 //like ExpirationDate
}

public class FoodItem : IFoodItem {
  ...
}

public class SandwichItem : IFoodItem {
  ...
}
```

So, in your example you would have to change any reference of FoodItem to IFoodItem.

If you don't know beforehand the type they are going to share you could take a look into generics to make your Inventory class more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: "You are going to have"

One of the easier ways would be to inherit from the FoodItem on your Sandwich class.

```
public class Sandwich : FoodItem
{
    public float rating = 0;
    public List<string> listOfIngredients = new List<string>();
    public Sandwich(){}

}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, modified it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be too advanced right now, butsince the `Inventory` class is basically a wrapper around a generic `List<T>` and doesn't require anything from the type itself, you could make it generic so it will work with *any* type:

```
public class Inventory<T>
{
    public List<T> container = new List<T>();
    public int inventorySlots = 1;

    public Inventory() { }

    public Inventory(int Slots)
    {
        inventorySlots = Slots;
    }

    public bool TryAddItemToInventory(T item)
    {
        if (!IsInventoryFull())
        {
            container.Add(item);
            return true;
        }

        Debug.Log("Inventory is full");
        return false;
    }

    public T RemoveItemFromInventory()
    {
        if (!IsInventoryEmpty())
        {
            T item = container[0];
            container.RemoveAt(0);
            return item;
        }

        Debug.Log("Inventory is empty: No item to take");
        return default(T);
    }

    public bool IsInventoryEmpty()
    {
        return container.Count == 0;
    }

    public bool IsInventoryFull()
    {
        return container.Count == inventorySlots;
    }
}
```